# Search results based on segment / Structure top parent

Tags: structure, low-search, supersearch

Is it possible to make a search on only subpages from the top segment? Example:

1) The user is on www.example.com/products/product-title/ and do a search on this site
2) The search results displays children of their top parent, /products

The reason why I want this is because I have several sections of the site that has been build up with exactly the same channels and structure. In other words, www.example.com/products/ and www.example.com/about/ is build up the same way, just with different content, and when I'm in "about" I only want to search articles that belong to that parent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to use conditionals and only search certain channels based off the segment. Basically showing a different search form per segment. Or maybe you could use the segment in the search parameter?

Comment: Well, the channels are the same, so I would have to do a conditional based on the page URL then. Maybe it's possible to do an AND-search, where one of the parameters is page_url and {segment_1} is hardcoded in the form tag somehow...? Not sure if Super Search or Low Replace would allow this, though.